# XPS Files Received Through TcpClient are Corrupt

Tags: c#, printing, tcpclient, xps

I am trying to create a "virtual printer" application in C# that receives print jobs over the network, parses the raw print data for certain information, and then saves the document into a database.  A modified version of the following class is working for postscript print jobs (it saves the incoming data to a valid .prn file, just as though the printer was set to print to the "FILE:" port.)  When I try to capture .XPS documents from Microsoft XPS Document Writer, though, the documents cannot be opened.  Valid XPS files should also be valid ZIP files if the extension is renamed, and this doesn't work either.  When I print the same document to the FILE: port and then to my application, and I compare the results in Notepad++, there is a 5-character difference in the length of the data, but it looks identical (it is not plaintext so it's difficult to look at, but the first few characters and last few characters appear to be the same).  The file saved the "normal" way works fine, but the file generated by my code does not.

More generally speaking, I'm trying to receive arbitrary data through a TCP port and write it to a file.  My solution is "close" but not working.  I don't know what kind of encoding XPS uses, but I am using ASCII for postscript and I have tried ASCII and UTF8 for this XPS version.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Here is the relevant part of my code:

```html
class XPSListener
    {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;
        private string instanceName = "";
        private string fileShare = (Settings.Default.SharedPath.Substring(Settings.Default.SharedPath.Length - 1) == @"\") ? Settings.Default.SharedPath : Settings.Default.SharedPath + @"\"; // use SharedPath setting value - append backslash if it isn't already there.

        public XPSListener(string initInstanceName, Int32 initPort)
        {
            this.instanceName = initInstanceName;
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, initPort);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }

        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            try
            {
                this.tcpListener.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Socket Error 1 - " + e.StackTrace);
            }

            while (true)
            {
                //blocks until a client has connected to the server
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                //create a thread to handle communication with connected client
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(AcceptXPSData));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }

        private void AcceptXPSData(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            string tempFilePath = fileShare + "XPStemp_" + instanceName + ".oxps";

            byte[] message = new byte[65536];
            int bytesRead;
            string input;

            while (true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    //blocks until a client sends a message
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 65536);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Bytes read: " + bytesRead.ToString());  
                }
                catch
                {
                    //a socket error has occured
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    //the client has disconnected from the server
                    break;
                }

                //message has successfully been received
                if (instanceName != "DontPrint")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(instanceName + " Receiving Data");
                    //ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                        {
                            input = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                            sw.Write(input);
                            // first capture this input and write it to an xps file.  This file can be converted to PDF at a later time by Ghostscript
                            // but we will still have access to the temp file for parsing purposes.
                        }
                    }
                }
                
               
            }

            tcpClient.Close();

            // processXPS();
        }
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I am using the Microsoft XPS Document Writer print driver, just trying to use a different port to send the results to my application rather than prompting the user to save to the hard drive.  The reason for that is to automate the way that files are named and stored.  This will be a nightmare to support if files get lost every time a user names it incorrectly.

Comment: Well, you can use the binary editor in Visual Studio to see what the _precise_ difference between the files is. I still don't understand how `TcpClient` is involved here, but it's not corrupting your data, I can tell you that much. You're not using it correctly -- there's no reason to believe expect that an entire file's worth of data will necessarily be received in a single call to `Read()`. Re encoding: if you're just writing the data to a file, don't interpret it at all...just write the bytes straight to the file. XML (and so XPS) uses UTF8, but it doesn't seem like that should matter here.

Comment: I'm not blaming TCPClient, I just have a bug.  Read() is in a loop - it fills a buffer, then appends to the file until no more data is coming in.  The debug results from the code read "Bytes Read: 65536 Bytes Read: 65536  Bytes Read: 45888  Bytes Read: 0" - the buffer filled twice and then read the remaining 45888 bytes.  This totals 172.8 kb, which is the exact size of the file I get when I "print to file the normal way", but interestingly enough, the file my program generates is 310kb, not 173 kb as debug would indicate.  Binary Editor shows "similar data" but a lot of extra garbage in mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems in your code, one of them almost certainly the reason the file you write is incorrect:

1. You keep reopening the file you're writing to, rather than just opening it once.
2. You are interpreting the bytes you receive as text and then re-encoding them.

The first issue is more of an efficiency/file-locking issue than a correctness problem. But the second is a big problem.

As you seem to be aware, an XPS file is basically a .zip file. That means that while the underlying data is XML (i.e. UTF8), the file itself is a compressed binary file. You can't interpret that as text in any meaningful way.

You should simply write the bytes you read straight to the file. A better version of your code would look like this:

```
private void AcceptXPSData(object client)
{
    string tempFilePath = fileShare + "XPStemp_" + instanceName + ".oxps";

    using (TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client)
    using (NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        clientStream.CopyTo(fs);
    }

    // processXPS();
}
```

If you actually want to monitor the I/O as it occurs, you can deal with it explicitly, but still much more simply than your code was:

```
private void AcceptXPSData(object client)
{
    string tempFilePath = fileShare + "XPStemp_" + instanceName + ".oxps";

    using (TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client)
    using (NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        byte[] message = new byte[65536];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(message, 0, bytesRead);

            // Add logging or whatever here
        }
    }

    // processXPS();
}
```

Note that if you want to handle exceptions, you need to handle only those you specifically expect might happen, and for which you have a reasonable way to deal with. Bare `catch` clauses, or broad `catch (Exception)` should be avoided in code like this.

Comment: Great, thank you!  The first solution is exactly what I needed and it works perfectly - I can worry about any other requirements once the temp file is written. Thanks for the quick responses!